# Modify JSon format returned by an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JQuery plugin where I have the following:

```
transformResult: function(response, originalQuery) {

}
```

Inside this function I need to convert the originalQuery Json data:

```
[
  { "Id": 4, "Title": "Title 4" },
  { "Id": 2, "Title": "Title 2" }
]
```

Into the response Json data format:

```
{
  suggestions: [
    { data: "4", value: "Title 4" },
    { data: "2", value: "Title 2" }
  ]
}
```

Id is the data and Title is the value.

How can I do this?

Thank you,
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr =[
  { "Id": 4, "Title": "Title 4" },
  { "Id": 2, "Title": "Title 2" }
]

var obj = {suggestions : []};

$.each(arr, function(i, o) {
    obj.suggestions.push({name : o.Id, value : o.Title});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dQfHJ/)